# QMediaPlayer state not stopped when status changed to end of media

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qmediaplayer

I have a problem using `QMediaPlayer.mediaStatusChanged`.

According to Qt5.7 documentation, when media status is changed to `EndOfMedia`, the QMediaPlayer state should be `StoppedState`:

> Playback has reached the end of the current media. The player is in the StoppedState.
>
> [Qt5.7](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#MediaStatus-enum)

However, the state is not stopped. Here is a sample that reproduces the issue:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent

class MediaPlayer(QMediaPlayer):
    default = 'test.mp3'

    def __init__(self):
        super(MediaPlayer, self).__init__()
        self.mediaStatusChanged[QMediaPlayer.MediaStatus].connect(self.media_status_changed)

        self.setup_media(self.default)

    def setup_media(self, media):
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(media)
        self.setMedia(QMediaContent(url))

    def media_status_changed(self, status):
        if status == QMediaPlayer.EndOfMedia:
            print(self.state() == QMediaPlayer.StoppedState) # I get False
            # self.state() is QMediaPlayer.PlayingState


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = MediaPlayer()
    m.play()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does anyone face the same problem?
I can fix the problem with a workaround but I think it may be a Qt problem.

Comment: I can confirm this. It may be the state will shortly after change but the experience seems to contradict the documentation (at least for the C++ QT documentation). It may be a bug.

Comment: Btw. what is your workaround?

Comment: I have updated the question with workarounds, personally I use the first one, I just force stop before processing, but I don't like either method 1 or method 2, if you think of a better one, let me know, thanks.

Comment: Works fine for me on Linux using Qt-5.7 and PyQt-5.7 (gstreamer backend + alsa).

Comment: then, it must be a windows issue, also I tried with C++ code running on Qt Creator (Qt 5.7), it's the same problem.

Comment: @Darkos Yes, I think it is a Windows issue too. Why don't you create an answer instead stating it seems to be a Windows issue and presenting your workaround there and edit the question so that it just deals with the problem, not with possible solutions. That looks much better and gives me or others the chance to upvote your ideas. I think this would be useful for others having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported the [issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-57197) to Qt as it seems to be a Windows only bug :

Possible workarounds to fix the problem :

1. Force stop before processing

   ```
   def media_status_changed(self, status):
       if status == QMediaPlayer.EndOfMedia:
           super(MediaPlayer, self).stop()
           # process
   ```
2. Poll until getting `StoppedState`

   ```
   def media_status_changed(self, status):
       if status == QMediaPlayer.EndOfMedia:
           while not (self.state() == QMediaPlayer.StoppedState):
               time.sleep(0.1)
           # process
   ```

I will add here any update regarding the Qt issue.

**EDIT:** issue updated and fixed in Qt v5.10.1